# No puedo entrar a mysql en debian

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Al instalar MySql-Workbrench , me ha desconfigurado MySQL y phpMyAdmin, dejando de funcionar. He tratado de instalarlo nuevamente y me da el siguiente error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")

Answer (score 1):

Revisa el archivo `my.cnf`,(Normalmente está en `/etc/mysql/`) y revisa que el socket esté bien definido;

Revisa también que el **bind address** en este archivo sea localhost.

```
bind-address=localhost #Si tan sólo te conectarás al servidor desde local.
bind-address=0.0.0.0 #Para permitir conexiones desde cualquier dirección.
```

Puedes comprobar si el servicio de mysqld está activo con este comando

```
systemctl status mysqld.service
```

(Suponiendo que tu distribución esté basada en systemd)

En caso de que el servicio no esté activo, puedes arrancarlo con este comando:

```
sudo systemctl start mysqld.service
```

Comment: por favor muestrale al usuario como debe estar el bind address, para conexiones exclusivas o abiertas

Comment: @JackNavaRow editado, gracias por la sugerencia.